# attribute error while trying to connect python to mysql. How do i fix it?

Tags: python, mysql

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the connector in cmd (the latest version), still doesn't help. Please provide some alternative solutions to the problem.

[image]

and this is the code:

[image]

Comment: Paste the code (pared down to the minimum required to show the problem), please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've pasted the code...pls check

Comment: You've posted a picture of the code, you didn't paste it as you should have.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this platform… I'm not sure how to post the code as it is, so I decided to paste the picture instead.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly make sure you're installing the correct package via pip. You need to run the following code:

`pip install mysql-connector-python`

Then check the authentication plugin you're using:

```
SELECT User,plugin FROM mysql.user
```

I had a similar problem and I followed this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/mysql/comments/l1tg06/mysql_connector_python_error_attributeerror/). It has something to do with the default authentication plugin. I hope I was of help. Peace